# Music in episode 10 of cowboy Bebop

Tags: music, cowboy-bebop

I would like to know if someone could tell me the name of a song in Cowboy Bebop, in episode 10, the one about Jet’s story?
It’s at the end of the episode at ~ 18:20 when he arrests his ex girlfriend and her new boyfriend.
Thanks you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The song name is ELM. https://cowboybebop.fandom.com/wiki/Ganymede_Elegy. Everything that you want to know about the episode 10 is on wiki fandom. Not only for the 10th episode but for every other episode in the series and for other animes too.Check it out.Have a great day:)